# Magento 2.1 - cron job runnoing every 2 minutes instead of 1 minute

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, crontab

I created a cron job and ***set it up to run every 1 minute, but it just runs every 2 minutes instead. I have NO idea what is going on?***

Any hint on why the cron task is executed every 2 minutes rather than every minute ?

[image: cron group image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your system cron. Make sure it is set `* * * * *` to run every minute. On linux you can run the command `crontab -l` to list all the cron for that user.

Comment: its every minute.. i jsut have no idea why magento is not firing the cron task.. i ended creating a cron job directly on the server that excute a magento url ! i know its not the right way, but its work around